# ASP.NET  Site architecture issue

Tags: asp.net, language-agnostic, architecture

Due to the nature of the way the website I am working on was designed I have an issue I now must resolve.
I will try to write this question as language-independent but the site is done in ASP.Net with C#.

### Overview

The structure of our site looks like this for any given "object":

- ASPX Page

  - Multiple UserControls (ascx    pages)

    - Textboxes, Comboboxes, Labels,
      Buttons, etc.

What this means is, if we have a User page and that page might have 3 UserControls.  One for User Information (Name, email, etc.), one for Address (City, State, Zip, etc.) and one for Regional Settings (Time zone, language, etc.)

All of these fields on the 3 UserControls are all stored in the same table in the database.

Now, we are using DataBinding and EntityFrameworks to fill in the data and this means that when we save an object, we are actually calling save 3 times (1 per UserControl).

> (Language-Agnostic: We don't actually
>   assign values like `User.Name =
>   "Bob"`, it is handled by a Framework)

Because the UserControl only knows about the fields it contains, when the Databinding saves it "thinks" the other fields are now blank. (i.e. Address control saves and now "Email" and "Name" are null values).  To "fix" this there is a method called "MapOldToNew" which goes out and grabs the old record and fills in the values on the New object that is about to be saved.  This is generic, which means we don't have a method on the Address Usercontrol that says "go get the Name and Email fields and fill them in", instead it loops through all the properties of the Entity(object) and if a value is `NULL` on the New object but `NOT NULL` on the Old object (the one currently in the database about to be overwritten) it will make the New value equal to the Old value.

### The Problem

Dates.  We allow NULL dates in our database.

If a User fills in "Birthday" and saves, they now have a Birthday value in the field in the database.
If they go back and clear out the Birthday field on the web page and save, the `MapOldToNew` method grabs the old record, sees that Birthday is not null there and is Null on the New object about to be saved, it will override the New value (NULL) with the Old value ('7/23/1981' for example).

### Solutions?

1. Rework our system to not use
   UserControls but instead have all
   controls on the same Page, thereby
   reducing the number of times we need
   to Save and not requiring
   `MapOldToNew`.  For now, let's
   assume this is an impossible
   solution (even though it is the one
   I feel like should be done for
   plenty of reasons).
2. Store all
   dates as Strings and do conversion
   on Load and Save. (Strings don't
   have the same problem because once a
   string has been modified it is now
   an empty string, and not NULL)
3. Do not allow NULL dates in the
   database and always store
   `DateTime.MinValue` and do not
   display it On Load.

Those are the ideas I have come up with off the top of my head.  For arguments sake, let's assume #1 is not possible (because I have a feel management won't like the time it will take to accomplish).

**How would you "fix" this?**

**Another Explanation**

Here is the problem broken down more.
User Record has 2 fields.  Name and Birthdate.
Assume that there is 1 ASPX Page with 2 UserControls (ascx).
UserControl1 has a single DatePicker DataBound to "BirthDate".
UserControl2 has a single TextBox DataBound to "Name".
When UserControl1 calls Update on the ObjectContext the User object it sends looks like this:

```
{ Name = NULL, BirthDate = 8/13/1980 }
```

MapOldToNew looks at the Database Record and sees that Name should be "Bob" so it fills the value in and the record saves.

UserControl2 calls Update now and the User object looks like this:

```
{ Name = "John", BirthDate = NULL }
```

MapOldToNew sees that BirthDate is NULL so it overwrites it with 8/13/1980 from the database and the record saves and the database has the correct values.

Now assume the user goes back in and deletes the BirthDate value.  When UserControl2 calls MapOldToNew, it sees that BirthDate is NULL (which the user wants) and overwrites it from the Database.
If it DIDN'T overwrite it from the database, it would always save it as NULL and the user would never be able to set the BirthDate.

Comment: Of _course_ the problem is language-agnostic. Otherwise it would be possible that you would not have exactly the same problem if you were programming in VB.NET.

Comment: Well yes, but it is sort of ASP.Net agnostic too.  Look at it from an MVC pattern viewpoint.  A View has multiple SubViews that all call the same Controller.Save with a partially populated Model, so they all call MapOldToNew which overwrites NULL dates with values from the database.

Comment: Your problem is the `MapOldToNew`-function. I'm unfamiliar with Entity-Framework, but it must be possible to load the old values from database, override the columns from the UC and save it. It would be even better if it wold be possible(isn't it?) to update the record partly(only the changed columns).

Comment: After googling a few minutes i've found [Stub Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx). Have a look at this video: http://www.screencast.com/t/ZGQyY2I5ZWE

Comment: @Tim - That may be a thing to look at but it would require manually populating about 50+ entities on 100+ UserControls

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor MapOldToNew to understand nullable types. Im assuming you have a nullable date (for ex. datetime? or Nullable  and if so - do not make the assumption of overwriting if null.

Also in the future consider MVC or for WebForms consider Dynamic Data because of the mapping of types to models.
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20Data

Comment: Yes but HOW would you refactor MapOldToNew in this case?  If a Date is NULL on an Updating Entity, how do we know if it is NULL because the user blanked it out, or if it is NULL because it just wasn't in the UserControl calling Update?

Comment: If you are always doing all three updates, then you surely don't want to all save three times. You need to merge this into either one single model that maps the values from each user control before saving it or create a new composite control to handle this. If you dont want to refactor that to have one save, then you need to only update that bit of information - and not care about the rest. IE your update proc only needs to know if address is null, update to null. if address is not null, assign a value - and don't touch any other field. Three updates though-I'd definitely look to refactor that

Comment: I completely agree with you on refactoring that.  The problem is that my example isn't the real life situation, just a simplified explanation.  In reality there are probably 50+ Entities with hundreds of UserControls that would have to be refactored.  What I am looking for is a way to do it without refactoring.  I am pretty sure it isn't possible, but I was hoping a smarter mind than mine could think of a way.

Comment: But if you all go through this common method then just refactor that method. If this OldToNew method assumes it will keep the original value - then you need to change that behavior in that method - there is no other way without refactoring everything else. You have an advantage in that you go through a common method - not seeing the whole system and only a simplified case thats the way it seems to me, So - can you change the MapOldToNew to change this null behavior? Can you post an example of why this would fail say - because of entity behavior for example?

Comment: Posting a different explanation above.

Comment: "When UserControl1 calls Update on the ObjectContext the User object it sends looks like this:"   why is the first user control sending in both fields?

Comment: Because it is DataBound.  We use an ObjectDataSource that grabs a full Entity, then binds only the fields it has, then when they Update the object is no longer full and has only the values of the fields contained on it, if we saved like that then all the other fields would get overwritten with NULL so we call MapOldToNew.  If this is NOT correct of how Databinding should work, please let me know because I have very little knowledge of Databinding.